# jquery window resize not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I'm trying to make a menu where sub menus are opened on hover but when on mobile (width < 800) sub menus should be triggered on click.

I made this jquery which is not working, it works on hover but when you re-size window its still triggered on hover not on click.

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".menu ul li").hover(function () {
        $('li > ul').not($(this).children("ul").slideToggle(200)).hide();
    });

});
$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() <= 800) {
        $(".menu ul li").click(function () {
            $('li > ul').not($(this).children("ul").slideToggle(200)).hide();
        });
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  background: #333;
}
.menu:before,
.menu:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.menu:after {
  clear: both;
}
.menu > ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.menu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  background: #e9e9e9;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.menu > ul > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1.5em 3em;
  display: block;
  outline: 0 none;
}
.menu > ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
  background: #333;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
  left: 0;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .menu ul > li {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .menu ul > li > ul {
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                <ul>
                    This is also mega menu
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Who are we?</a>
                <ul>
                    This is mega menu
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</li></a>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

How can i do with jquery to change from on hover to on click when the window is resized or its below 800px?

Comment: I dont see any issue with resize function, put a console.log just before  if   "($(window).width() <= 800) {" and you can check that. I doubt this part is not sync with logic
$(".menu ul li").click(function () {
            $('li > ul').not($(this).children("ul").slideToggle(200)).hide();
        });.

Comment: You can use `.off()` to unbind the `hover` event but that should also be bound with `.on()` method.

Comment: @user2181397 the syntax is good, when i only put click function on document ready, submenus are triggered on click, and when i put only hover function the submenus are triggered on hover. So i think thats fine. I just cant put them together with window resize. In that case only hover function is working

Comment: I am confused with the logic. Inside a resize function you are again calling a click function. It inter you will first resize the window then you have to clcik on the element. I am not sure what does that mean.Please create a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this script

```
$(document).ready(function () {

       $(".menu ul li").hover(function () {
          if ($(window).width() > 800) {

                $('li > ul').not($(this).children("ul").slideToggle(200)).hide();
          }

        });
         $(".menu ul li").click(function () {
          if ($(window).width() <= 800) {

                $('li > ul').not($(this).children("ul").slideToggle(200)).hide();
          }
        });

});
```

Comment: This is the only solution that is working perfectly!!! Thank you so much for your help sir!

Comment: Can you please explain me why does this work but without even calling resize function. Is resize function even suitable for this application? Im a just trying to learn jquery

Comment: @Jai Im sorry mate whats funny, sorry if I did not understand your solution, im just a learner

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `.off()` method to unbind the events attached and make sure to bind the other events with `.on()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menu ul li").on('mouseenter', function() {
    $('> ul', this).stop().slideToggle(200); // this would do, as per context applied with "this"
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 800) {
      $(".menu ul li").off().on('click', function() {
        $('> ul', this).stop().slideToggle(200); // this would do, context applied with "this"
      });
    }
  }).resize(); // trigger the resize() event on dom ready.
}); // <-----------wrap everything in the doc ready block
```

### [Plnkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/0Jga5ztIwYhynVq9Bz4D?p=preview)

---

Even a better one:

```
// make a global function which toggles the submenus.
function submenutoggler() {
  $('> ul', this).stop().slideToggle(200); // .stop() will tackle the multiple clicks.
}

$(document).ready(function() {    
  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 800) {
      $(".menu ul li").off().on('click', submenutoggler); // if mobile bind click
    }else{
      $(".menu ul li").on('mouseenter', submenutoggler); // if desktop bind mouseenter
    }
  }).resize(); // trigger the resize to execute at dom ready.

}); // <----wrap it within dom ready block.
```

### [Updated plnkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/0Jga5ztIwYhynVq9Bz4D?p=preview)

Comment: this is not working, when i resize its still triggered on hover

Comment: @riogrande check the plnkr demo, is it working for you?

Comment: the second script might be the solution for me but something is going on with hovers, i need to play witih it. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".menu ul li").on('hover',function () {
        $('li > ul').not($(this).children("ul").slideToggle(200)).hide();
    });

});
$(window).on('resize'function () {
    if ($(window).width() <= 800) {
        $(".menu ul li").on('click',function () {
            $('li > ul').not($(this).children("ul").slideToggle(200)).hide();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: check by giving log inside your condition

Comment: Thanks for help, but its not working, now neither hover or click works?

Answer (score 0):

You need to unbind the event before the binding new event. I have modified your code see the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/sachinkk/nu1dbp5a/

Also, made the changes in HTML. Hope this will helpful.

> Make sure while loading the page, the size of a page should be more
>   than 800px. (events are binding after page resizes)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".menu ul li").hover(function () {
        $('li > ul').not($(this).children("ul").slideDown(200)).hide();
    },function(){
     $('li > ul').not($(this).children("ul").slideUp(200)).hide();
    });

});
$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() <= 800) {
        $(".menu ul li").unbind('hover');
        $(".menu ul li").unbind('click');
        $(".menu ul li").click(function (e) {
            $('li > ul').not($(this).children("ul").slideToggle(200)).hide();
        });
    }
    else{
        if ($(window).width() > 800){
        $(".menu ul li").unbind('click');
            $(".menu ul li").unbind('hover');
        $(".menu ul li").hover(function () {
            $('li > ul').not($(this).children("ul").slideDown(200));
        },function(){
            $('li > ul').not($(this).children("ul").slideUp(200));
        });      
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  background: #333;
}
.menu:before,
.menu:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.menu:after {
  clear: both;
}
.menu > ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.menu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  background: #e9e9e9;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.menu > ul > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1.5em 3em;
  display: block;
  outline: 0 none;
}
.menu > ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
  background: #333;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
  left: 0;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .menu ul > li {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .menu ul > li > ul {
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>This is also mega menu</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Who are we?</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>This is mega menu</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: I was able to reproduce that with much less code, with not using bind and unbind, its working when i refresh page when its resized, but its not solution i was looking for. But thanks for helping me!